# How to integrate maven with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to integrate maven with Eclipse and it returns the following error "Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.6.2.20150902-0002 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.6.2.20150902-0002)". I have tried using this URL "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" and I still get the error message.

Comment: you could also open the "Error log" view in Eclipse for more information. Can you check and provide us with any other error message from "Error log"? Also, what is your Eclipse's version?

Comment: Many of the packaged Eclipse downloads already include m2e.

Comment: perhaps switch to a newer version of Eclipse which comes with maven already integrated

Comment: I  have downloaded a newer version and it has worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this can be considered as an answer. Select a Project, try to press Shift-alt-x and then after a menu appeared right corner press M. After that write "clean install" and hit enter.

Comment: That's a Maven command, yes? The question appears not be able to actually install the Maven plugin

Comment: then he might can install the latest eclipse. The latest eclipse has intergraded this plugin.

Comment: If you look at the comments -- he did. He installed a newer version and was able to successfully download Maven.

Comment: Ok you are right. He should write this as an answer and accept it.